# Creating subdirectories and sorting files based on filename PYTHON

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, shutil

I have a large directory with many part files with their revisions, I want to recursively create a new folder for each part, and then move all of the related files into that folder. I am trying to do this by isolating a 7 digit number which would be used as an identifier for the part, and all the related filenames would also include this number.

```
import os
import shutil
import csv
import glob
from fnmatch import fnmatch, filter
from os.path import isdir, join
from shutil import copytree, copy2, Error, copystat
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns


dirname = ' '

# pattern =  '*???????*'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
    for fpath in files:
        print(fpath)
        if fpath[0:6].isdigit():
            matchdir = os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(fpath)))
            partnum = str(fpath[0:6])
            pattern = str(partnum)
            filematch = fnmatch(files, pattern)
            print(filematch)
            shutil.move(filematch, matchdir)
```

This is what I have so far, basically I'm not sure how to get the original filename and use it as the matching patter for the rest of the files. The original filename I want to use for this matching pattern is just a 7 digit number, and all of the related files may have other characters (REV-2) for example.

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  You have successfully pulled a 7-digit number from the front of the file name, stored it in both **partnum** and **pattern**, and looked up other files that contain that 7-digit string.  The original file name is still safe in **fpath**.  What part of this doesn't work, and what *does* it do instead?

Answer (score 2):

## Don't overthink it

I think you're getting confused about what `os.walk()` gives you - recheck the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). `dirs` and `files` are just a list of *names* of the directories / files, not the full paths.

Here's my suggestion. Assuming that you're starting with a directory layout something like:

```
directory1
    1234567abc.txt
1234567abc.txt
1234567bcd.txt
2234567abc.txt
not-interesting.txt
```

And want to end with something like:

```
directory1
    1234567
        abc.txt
1234567
    abc.txt
    bcd.txt
2234567
    abc.txt
not-interesting.txt
```

If that's correct, then there's no need to rematch the files in the directory, just operate on each file individually, and make the part directory only if it doesn't already exist. I would also use a regular expression to do this, so something like:

```
import os
import re
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
    for fname in files:
        # Match a string starting with 7 digits followed by everything else.
        # Capture each part in a group so we can access them later.
        match_object = re.match('([0-9]{7})(.*)$', fname)
        if match_object is None:
            # The regular expression did not match, ignore the file.
            continue

        # Form the new directory path using the number from the regular expression and the current root.
        new_dir = os.path.join(root, match_object.group(1))
        if not os.path.isdir(new_dir):
            os.mkdir(new_dir)

        new_file_path = os.path.join(new_dir, match_object.group(2))

        # Or, if you don't want to change the filename, use:
        new_file_path = os.path.join(new_dir, fname)

        old_file_path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        shutil.move(old_file_path, new_file_path)
```

Note that I have:

- Switched the sense of the condition, we continue the loop immediately if the file is not interesting. This is a useful pattern to use to make sure that your code does not get too heavily indented.
- Changed the name of `fpath` to `fname`. This is because it's not a path but just the name of the file, so it's better to call it `fname`.

Please clarify the question if that's not what you meant!

[edit] to show how to copy the file without changing its name.

Comment: Thanks! How could I change this to include files that don't start with the number? I tried adding a '*' before the ([0-9]{7})(.*)$ but I got an error

Comment: For some reason, when the files are moved over, their names (which are the directory name) are deleted. I think the code is taking the characters from the file names to create the directory names, but I don't want the file name to be altered. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you want to match files that just contain 7 numbers, then instead of doing  `re.match(pattern, string)` you can do `re.search(pattern, string)`, which will match if `string` contains `pattern` anywhere in it. To get a better understanding of regular expressions check out [regular-expressions-info tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) which is how I learnt, and also make sure to read the python [regex docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: And I've updated my answer to show how to move the file without changing its name.

Comment: @Darya did that answer the question? If so, can you mark it as such, thanks!